# When I try to scaffolding in New Laravel Project with VueJs given error "$0.25rem and 0 are incompatible"

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am create a new Laravel project and Scaffold with VueJs so given error.
"SassError: 0.25rem and 0 are incompatible.
$return: append($return, max($value, 0));"

I am doing these steps:

1. composer create-project laravel/laravel blog
2. composer require laravel/ui
3. php artisan ui vue
4. npm install
5. npm run dev

When I doing npm run dev given the error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdJSR.png)

Comment: This is an issue with sass, what version of node are you using.

Comment: Node Version - 14.16.0